# How to run multiple Chrome debug windows for Flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, google-chrome-devtools, flutter-web

I am trying to debug my flutter web app and i can run from Android Studio a Chrome debug window to run my app in debug mode.

My web app is however complicated and i need to have multiple Chrome tabs / debug windows in order to test everything.

How can i do so please ?